# Generate Unique address for each users?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, address, daemon

I have PHP Based Web Bitcoin Wallet on localhost. I use simple Login system and basic bitcoin Json-RPC. 
In fact, everything is runing clearly, but my Bitcoin daemon giving same Bitcoin address to all users.

I want, Unique bitcoin address for every user? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON-RPC has a method called `getnewaddress` that will generate a new private-/public-keypair and return it to the caller. You can use this to generate a new address for each user. In order to track the balances of users I'd suggest grouping a user's addresses in an account associated with the user by calling `getaccountaddress` with the user ID or the username. You can then use the `getbalance <user>` call to check its current balance. However, there are some [caveats](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained#Account_Weaknesses) when grouping addresses with accounts.

Comment: thx bro. Can u see my other problem? 
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43775/json-rpc-connection-problem